# Rows inserted, updated or deleted using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to know how many rows inserted, deleted or updated in my lookup stored procedure, using another stored procedure in SQL Server.

Can someone help me how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: So in your lookup store procedure you need to implement a logic using Output Clause which will give you the numbers. Then you can insert these numbers into a  Table something like AuditLog which will have Before and After value for Insert/Update/Delete for the given Procedure every time it runs or called This is the logic please have a look, http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/156204/ , second option is using Trigger

Answer (score 1):

If your application needs to know how many rows a stored procedure affected, then *that stored procedure* should be programmed to tell you this answer in what it returns.

Architecturally speaking, you don't want "dependencies," or "magic knowledge," or "assumptions" to exist – *"variables don't, and constants aren't."*  Your application should treat every stored-procedure as a "black box," and every stored-procedure should treat other stored-procedures likewise.  If you need to know what a stored-procedure did, *that procedure, alone,* should be the one to give answer.  ("Thus, it is dependent only upon itself.")